# null pointer exception error that I can't figure it out

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am new to programming and I have spent two days trying to figure out what is wrong with my program.  I have learnt a lot trying to fix this but I am not getting anywhere.

I couldn't figure out how to copy the error in logcat in eclipse so I will type out the error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.deweyx.MainActivity.OnCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xDisplay);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);            
            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the xml folder:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/display" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/xDisplay"
/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/padd"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
 />


<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/psub"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:id="@+id/bSub"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

logcat:

```
   12-19 02:11:36.423: D/AndroidRuntime(531): Shutting down VM
12-19 02:11:36.423: W/dalvikvm(531): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.deweyx/com.deweyx.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.deweyx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-19 02:11:36.444: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  ... 11 more
12-19 02:11:36.653: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-19 02:11:36.673: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-19 02:11:36.983: I/dalvikvm(531): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-19 02:11:36.993: I/dalvikvm(531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-19 02:11:52.452: I/dalvikvm(551): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-19 02:11:52.502: I/dalvikvm(551): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-19 02:11:52.783: D/AndroidRuntime(551): Shutting down VM
12-19 02:11:52.783: W/dalvikvm(551): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.deweyx/com.deweyx.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.deweyx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-19 02:11:52.793: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  ... 11 more
12-19 02:11:52.963: I/dalvikvm(551): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-19 02:11:52.963: I/dalvikvm(551): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-19 02:11:53.343: I/dalvikvm(551): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-19 02:11:53.353: I/dalvikvm(551): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: can you tell us which line is 27?

Comment: line 27 in my project is: add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);

Comment: Clean the project(Project->Clean).

Comment: agree with @Luksprog , it seems that you just need to clean the project to let Eclipse rebuilt the `R` references.

Comment: I tried cleaning and I still get the same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950097/is-there-a-way-to-get-copy-and-pastable-debug-output-in-the-android-sdk-emulator

Comment: If project-> clean doesn't help you then you need to restart your IDE!

Comment: your code is 100% correct...

Comment: I have restarted and there is still the error.  I am amazed at the quick and helpful responses.  I suppose I will have to try re-installing everything again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it crashes on the `findViewById` when looking for the id bAdd, this is probably because that id is not defined yet. Are you sure you are using the correct xml? What I mean is, are you sure you're using `activity_main.xml` as the XML layout? Because maybe you are looking in the wrong XML file, it has happened to me :-)

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that this is what I did wrong but at the same time so happy you fixed it!  Thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to learn a shortcut way to define button click?

Here is shortcut way to define click listener for any button.

**Step 1:** include android:onClick="btnAddButtonClick" inside your add button xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/padd"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:onClick="btnAddButtonClick"     <<----- android:onClick
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
 />
```

**Step 2:** Create a method inside your activity, with name the same value you have given inside onClick attribute:

```
public void btnAddButtonClick(View v) 
{
     counter++;
     display.setText("Your total is " + counter);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct just do `Project->Clean`

If it didn't help you then you need to restart your IDE!